# How to draw a stroke with Drawable in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable, stroke

I have a function that converts a resource to Bitmap, this function is used to draw a custom marker map.

I want to draw a stroke around the resource, i got some answers from stack overflow, but none of them worked so far.

This is my code:

```
fun getBitmapFromVector(
    context: Context,
    @DrawableRes vectorResourceId: Int,
    @ColorInt tintColor: Int
): BitmapDescriptor {
    val vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
        context.resources, vectorResourceId, null
    )
    if (vectorDrawable == null) {
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Requested vector resource was not found")
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()
    }
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val paintIcon = Paint()
    paintIcon.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paintIcon.color = Color.BLACK
    paintIcon.strokeWidth = 1f

    val paintStroke = Paint()
    paintStroke.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    paintStroke.color = tintColor

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val canvasStroke = Canvas()

    canvasStroke.drawBitmap(bitmap,10f,10f,paintStroke)

    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(vectorDrawable, tintColor)
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvasStroke)

    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val paintIcon = Paint()
paintIcon.style = Paint.Style.FILL // you assigned STROKE here
paintIcon.color = Color.BLACK
paintIcon.strokeWidth = 1f

val paintStroke = Paint()
paintStroke.style = Paint.Style.STROKE // you assigned FILL here
paintStroke.color = tintColor
```

Try changing those lines, which were commented

Comment: Nothing changed :(